# SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldExampleApplication.class, args);

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-boot, eclipse-plugin

the error is in the following line of code-

```
SpringApplication.run(HelloWorldExampleApplication.class, args);
```

it says-

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - The type org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced 
     from required .class files
    - The method run(Class<?>, String...) from the type SpringApplication refers to the missing type 
     ConfigurableApplicationContext
```

I've tried running command `"mvn dependency:purge-local-repository"` and it says mvn not recognised as int/ext command.

i'm using springboot sts plugin in eclipse IDE.
pls. help as i'm a beginner.

pom file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.Ideng</groupId>
    <artifactId>helloworld</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>HelloWorldExample</name>
    <description>hello world example</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Check if maven is installed and on system path. Use maven configuration to locate maven in IDE.

Comment: We need your pom file, and you need to install maven properly for your command line.

Comment: here is pom file-

Comment: i've installed maven plugin in ide itself. do i need to install it otherwise

Answer (score 0):

i changed the spring version from 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 SNAPSHOT while creating the project from start and it worked